# Rails 4 + Devise: Missing "admins/sign_up" route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, admin

I have a Rails app, v4, and just need ot modify some "old" code - I need to add some attributes to the [admin model](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-an-Admin-Role).

When I tried to add a new admin user and set to the browser "/admins/sign_up", I got an error message that the route doesn't exist.

Okay, so I checked all the Devise routes:

```
                new_admin_session GET      /admins/sign_in(.:format)                                                          devise/sessions#new
                    admin_session POST     /admins/sign_in(.:format)                                                          devise/sessions#create
            destroy_admin_session DELETE   /admins/admin_logout(.:format)                                                     devise/sessions#destroy
                   admin_password POST     /admins/password(.:format)                                                         devise/passwords#create
               new_admin_password GET      /admins/password/new(.:format)                                                     devise/passwords#new
              edit_admin_password GET      /admins/password/edit(.:format)                                                    devise/passwords#edit
                                  PATCH    /admins/password(.:format)                                                         devise/passwords#update
                                  PUT      /admins/password(.:format)                                                         devise/passwords#update
                 new_user_session GET      /users/login(.:format)                                                             devise/sessions#new
                     user_session POST     /users/login(.:format)                                                             devise/sessions#create
             destroy_user_session DELETE   /users/logout(.:format)                                                            devise/sessions#destroy
                    user_password POST     /users/secret(.:format)                                                            devise/passwords#create
                new_user_password GET      /users/secret/new(.:format)                                                        devise/passwords#new
               edit_user_password GET      /users/secret/edit(.:format)                                                       devise/passwords#edit
                                  PATCH    /users/secret(.:format)                                                            devise/passwords#update
                                  PUT      /users/secret(.:format)                                                            devise/passwords#update
```

How is possible that the routes for a new admin sign up is missing? Did I miss something?

Anyway, how to add this missing route?
When I look to the views, I see that in `admins/registrations/` is `new.html.erb` and there's a sign up form for a new admin.

How to display (under which URL) form and use it?

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT: Routes**

```
devise_for :admins, :path_names => {:sign_out => 'admin_logout'}
devise_for :users, :path_names => { :sign_in => 'login', :sign_out => 'logout', :password => 'secret',
                                    :confirmation => 'verification', :unlock => 'unlock', :registration => 'register',
                                    :sign_up => 'signup' }, :controllers => {:omniauth_callbacks => "omniauth_callbacks", :registrations => "registrations"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the missing `/admins/sign_up` route like the following:

```
devise_for :admins do
  get '/admins/sign_up' => 'devise/registrations#new'
end
```

This generates this route:

```
new_admin_registration GET    /admins/sign_up(.:format)               devise/registrations#new
```

and should fix your problem.

#### Update:

Remove this from your current routes file:

```
devise_for :admins, :path_names => {:sign_out => 'admin_logout'}
```

Add this to your routes file:

```
  devise_for :admins do
    get '/admins/sign_up' => 'devise/registrations#new'
  end
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried it but got the following error: `Invalid route name, already in use: 'new_admin_session' You may have defined two routes with the same name using the :as option, or you may be overriding a route already defined by a resource with the same naming`. -- if that route already exists, how is possible it's not accessible on `/admins/sign_up`?

Comment: Could you please post your routes.rb file? Then I can check what's the issue.

Comment: I created a new Rails app and added the exact same routes that you have posted and it already has the `'/admins/sign_up'`. See here:
https://gist.github.com/rakibulislam/be727389b66a3428bd1a#file-devise_routes-L12
However, I suggested a solution in my udpated answer. Please try that and let me know. (Thats working for me)